# JavaScript Calendar Table Style

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

Using JavaScript How could I make my web page detect the current day of the week and show it in a different background color from the rest of the page?
Also how can I make the web page detect the current day of the month and show it in a different text color from the rest of the page? 
This has to be done using JavaScript for the record.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>GETTING STARTED WITH BRACKETS</title>
        <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
   <style>
       body{
background-color:azure;
       }
       date border {
    border: 2px solid green;

       }
    </style>     
<th id = "demo"></th>    
<td id="demo1"></td>        
<table>
<tr>
<th>Sunday</th>
<td>1</td>  
<td>8</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>29</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
 <th>Monday</th>
<td>2</td>  
<td>9</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>30</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<td>3</td>  
<td>10</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>31</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<td>4</td>  
<td>11</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
<th>Thursday</th>
<td>5</td>  
<td>12</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>26</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Friday</th>
<td>6</td>  
<td>13</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>27</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
<th>Saturday</th>
<td>7</td>  
<td>14</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>28</td>
</tr>

<script>
var dateborder = document.getElementById(date).style.border=" 2px solid green";
for (var i == 0, i<date, i++);
if (i% 3 == 0);
date  border [i]="red";
else if (i% == 1);
date border[i]="orange";
var x = newDate(i);
getDate(x);
getFullYear(x);
</script>   



</table>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry if it isn't good. Im pretty lost in this. So I am not very sure how this will work.

Comment: Take a look at Date object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date Try to do it by yourself and come back if you can't get it to work adding your code to your question.

Comment: Can you change the page, or only add your javascript to it? If you can change the page, use the date in the id attribute of all date cells, then `getElementById()`. If you can't change the page, you will have to loop through all td tags to find the one that has the value of today.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to take a look at [JavaScript Get Date Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp). In particular

> getMonth()    Get the month as a number (0-11)
>
> getDate() Get the day as a number (1-31)

Then using [javascript selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_selectors.asp), you can [add classes to HTML elements](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_add_class.asp) to apply certain stylings.

Please do a quick research as you will find plenty of helpful information before asking questions, at least show effort on what you have accomplished and tried to try and solve the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, the internet at our school was not functioning. We had no access to w3schools. But thanks.